# Using value outside of domain to get the correct answer?

Tags: probability, statistics

If X is uniformly distributed on the interval [1,5] and $Y=e^X$, then find $f_Y(8)$

Then $f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{4y}$ $ln(1) \le y \le ln(5)$

$f_Y(8) = \frac{1}{4*8}=\frac{1}{32}$ which is the answer in the back of the book.

however ln(5) = 1.61

So why is this a valid question? Shouldn't the fact that y always being smaller than 8, restrict me from plugging in that value?

Comment: No, $Y$ takes on values in $[e^1,e^5]$ and $8$ is well within that interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $Y$ takes on values in $[e^1,e^5]$.

Then, for $y \in [e^1,e^5]$, 
$F_Y(y)=P(Y \leq y) = P(e^X \leq y) = P(X \leq \ln y) = \frac{\ln y - 1}{5-1}$. For $y < e^1, F_Y(y)=0$ and for $y>e^5$, $F_Y(y) = 1$.

Differentiating this with respect to $y$ gives the density of $y$ as $f_Y(y)= \frac{1}{4} \frac{1}{y}$ on $[e^1,e^5]$ and $f_Y(y) =0$ otherwise.

Evaluating at $y=8$ gives $f_Y(8)=\frac{1}{32}$.